# Can I delete my answer with upvote(s)?

Tags: discussion, support, deleted-answers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What can cause a post to be deleted, and what does that actually mean?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that-actually-mean)

Can I delete answer with upvote(s) which had given to somebody else's question? Am I going to lose the reputation, I got due to the upvote ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can delete your answer only if it is not an **accepted** answer. Deleting the answer will also reset the reputation you earn/loose from the upvotes/downvotes.

If your answer has 3 voteups then you may get `Disciplined` badge for deleting such answer, same as deleting answer with -3 votes can give you `Peer Pressure` badge.

Comment: And when that downvoted answer gets deleted, you would get those reputation back. Oh, look, I've got a `peer pressure` badge! :P

Comment: @ChrisK: I actually thought that same thing when they recently improved the turnaround time for reputation re-calculation.  Still, earning that badge involves giving a bad answer.  If someone wants a simple bronze badge _that_ badly then I guess they can just post a nonsense answer to get it.  Personally I think that price is too high, even if the rep is immediately returned.

Comment: Well, it's properly earned if the intent was there. In my case, my lesson was to never try and help with java-anything in the future. They're mean, elitist, snobby people.

Answer (score 2):

You can delete any answers you post, and any reputation associated with those posts will also be removed from your account.